# visual studio code remote preconfigure extensions

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

I have different docker images hosting code. Some are for java, some are python, some are node... I can boot a container via docker and connect to the running container with VS Code Remote Development over ssh (works great!) but each time I connect to a new image the extensions have to be loaded again.

I know that I can configure "Always Installed" extensions ( https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh#_managing-extensions ) but this re-downloads the extensions each time I login to a new container, and I don't see a way to separate the extensions by host, so the java extensions would get loaded when I'm connected to an image that only hosts python code.

So what I'd really like to do is to somehow bake in the extensions via the Dockerfiles for the various code projects. The idea being, that when I (or other developers that I would give this image to) connect to a container that's hosting java code, it also has the java extensions ready and installed for me.

Anyone done anything similar?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I just made a response on that over at [VSCODE remote container - avoid reinstall extensions on rebuild](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69635493/vscode-remote-container-avoid-reinstall-extensions-on-rebuild/72510477#72510477)

Basically, you cache the whole vscode-remote folder on a per-container basis. That will keep the installed extensions and state across restarts. Thats a start.

Second part of it is, don't click `Install` when the prompt offers you to install "Workspace Recommended Extensions", instead click `Install (do not sync)`. This won't install them onto all of your devices, only onto the container itself.

And finally, some extensions are simply incapable of playing nice. Its rare these days, but some simply still get installed into the parent window. At least, as long as you follow the number 2 above, they won't bother you much.