# VSCODE remote container - avoid reinstall extensions on rebuild

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-remote

I am currently working with a remote docker container which is running locally on my computer,  mainly Python.

I have several extensions listed on devcontainer.json so when the docker is build it install these package.
I am tryin to avoid reinstalling some of these extensions every time I rebuild or reopen the project.

Specially with Pylance and Python which require to reload the project within VScode.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

There is a detailed description on the official vscode docs:

[https://code.visualstudio.com/remote/advancedcontainers/avoid-extension-reinstalls][1]

This creates a docker volume on the host. The extensions will need to be installed inside the container only once because the files will be persisted on the host volume hence survive any container rebuilds.

Comment: link is dead :(

Answer (score 1):

Yo, put a volume over `/root/.vscode-server` or symlink the whole vscode server folder to a.tmp folder within the project, and then also put that folder into a persistant docker folume :)

```
# entrypoint.sh
echo "[Operation] Symlink vscode-server (for developers that use it)"
mkdir -p /app/.tmp/.vscode-server \
&& ln -s /app/.tmp/.vscode-server /root/.vscode-server
```

Comment: Is this answer relevant to my situation? I do "remote development" i.e. I use vscode to connect to a remote server. I install my vscode server in `scratch/local/tsturges/.vscode-server` which I specify in my local vscode `settings.json`. I don't understand the logic of this answer enough to generalise

Comment: As far as I understand you create a symbolic link between the normal vscode server installation directory to one inside your application. But I don't understand why that's helpful. And also what if I'm developing more than one application at one? But anyway maybe this answer isn

Comment: Hey Tom, its been a while so I don't remember 101% but I believe that my answer was besides the point. The OP was asking about a remote setup, and my answer is only relevant to Docker remote development.

Comment: Thanks this worked. Though I used docker-compose so the process is different (mounting) but the idea is the same.

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure what OP meant remote docker container running on local machine. I am going to assume that he meant building docker container in his local machine and then use `Dev Containers: Attach to Running Container` plugin to open a new VSCODE inside the container.

To combine what @beneM and an alternative to what @MrManafon said, if you are using `docker-compose.yml`, you can add a volume to the service you are attaching.

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  app:
    ... # other docker settings
    volumes:
      - ./app:/var/www/app:cached # volume of your project to container
      - ./.vscode-server:/root/.vscode-server # volume of the vscode plugins
```

This will create `./vscode-server/` in your root folder where plugins are stored.

Tip: add `./vscode-server/` in your `.gitignore`.